# Using a string in find command

Tags: jquery

Im using Jquery to show some elements and trying to do the same with for statement which fails.

Existing working code

```
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYIP').html("Validated").show()
$(this).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYDNS1').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYDNS2').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYGW').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYNM').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYNTP1').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYNTP2').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYHOST').html("Validated").show()
$( this ).closest('table').find('#DISPLAYID1').html("Validated").show()
```

New code not working

```
displayfields = ['#DISPLAYIP','#DISPLAYDNS1','#DISPLAYDNS2','#DISPLAYGW','#DISPLAYNM','#DISPLAYNTP1','#DISPLAYNTP2','#DISPLAYHOST','#DISPLAYID1']

    displayfields.forEach(function(i){
                                alert("displayfields = " + i)
                                $( this ).closest('table').find(i).html("Validated").show()
                                alert("Over" )

                            })
```

Comment: where are you getting $(this) from???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that you have a valid element for `$(this)`, you can use jquerys each to do this pretty easy, but you'll need to reference this to maintain scope.

```
var that = $(this);
$.each(displayfields, function(i, e){
   that.closest('table').find(displayfields[i]).html("Validated").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < displayfields.length; i++) {
    $( this ).closest('table').find(displayfields[i]).html("Validated").show()
}
```

Don't iterate Arrays with a for each because you will be iterating all Object properties. The order of Object property iteration is not guaranteed, the array indexes may not visited in the numeric order. Inherited properties of the Object are also enumerated.

Comment: it's not true, see spec of forEach. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

i already a value, as Element goes first

Answer (score 0):

not sure about this, in your code, but let's assume it's jquery widget for instance, if so:

```
var cachedTable =  $(this).closest('table');
    displayfields.forEach(function(i){
        console.log("displayfields = " + i);
        cachedTable.find(i).html("Validated").show();
    });
    console.log('done');
```

As + If all content you're trying to update is located into logical area, just do template for it, and build html, then do update. it will hugely reduce DOM calls,  1 instead of length of  array of ids

Answer (score 0):

As an `id` is unique within the document, why not simply:

```
$(displayFields.join(',')).html('validated').show();
```

If you really want to use native `forEach` I'd suggest:

```
displayFields.forEach(function(id){
    $(id).html('validated').show();
});
```

But mixing DOM and jQuery is needless, and with a compliant browser could just use native DOM:

```
displayFields.forEach(function(id){
    var elem = document.querySelector(id);
    elem.innerHTML = 'validated';
    elem.style.display = 'block';
});
```